# Upload form and upload.php in same page

Tags: php, forms, upload

i would ask you how can i set my post-upload messages (now in a new page called upload.php) in the same page where is the upload form.
My upload form code, in my html page uploadform.html, is:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

This form call an upload.php, where the results will be display.
My upload.php code is:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

So, i want that the echo results (for example  echo "File is not an image.") will be display upper than the UPLOAD FORM in my uploadform.html and not in a new page called upload.php!
Thank you!!

Comment: yes you can do by using session variable in same page post.but i think ajax is the good solution for you. you can use ajax for post after that returning your result from server side you can show return message using javascript. you can check [link](http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/)

Answer (score 0):

1) Just put the html below all codes in upload.php

```
?>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

Select image to upload:

2) Make sure no error is shown when form is not submitted. So all validations under upload.php should be under a condition isset($_POST["submit"]).

You can now rename the file to uploadform.php if you want. But it needs to be a PHP file, not a html file.